# Enable "install new software" from eclipse product

Tags: eclipse, product

I've created and eclipse product. I'd like to be able to install new software from this product. 
The "Install new software" menu option is available but once I scan an update site (or select an archive file) i receive an error "An internal error occurred during: "Contacting Software Sites".
java.lang.NullPointerException".
Any idea?

Comment: Look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory for a more detailed message.

Comment: Problem solved by adding the dependency: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.transport.ecf

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by adding the dependency: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.transport.ecf